# What is the quickest way to find the default region for a new AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just created a new account and have started configuring the AWS CLI. I have created a new IAM user and security credentials for that user. After entering the access id and secret key I am also asked the default region. What should I fill in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html):

> The Default region name identifies the AWS Region whose servers you want to send your requests to by default. This is typically the Region closest to you, but **it can be any Region**. For example, you can type us-west-2 to use US West (Oregon). This is the Region that all later requests are sent to, unless you specify otherwise in an individual command.

Thus you can specify the default region whichever you want to use to launch your resources. It can be geographically closest to you, but it can be any other as well.

Also some services are not available in all regions (e.g. Alexa for Business). Thus if you wanted to work witch such services, your default region would be one when the service is available.

Comment: yeah, i was actually looking at the case when the CLI is being configured the first time after installation

Comment: @AnubhavPandey It is up to _you_ to specify the region that you want the CLI to use by default. You could leave it blank, but you would then need to add `--region xxx` to every command.

Answer (score 1):

1. Type `https://aws.amazon.com/console/` in the search bar
2. Enter the email id and password for your root user account
3. When the console is loading after successful login you will see that the url shows the current default region for your newly created account[image]

Comment: Default region is defined as: "The Default region name identifies the AWS Region whose servers you want to send your requests to by default. This is typically the Region closest to you, but **it can be any Region**. For example, you can type us-west-2 to use US West (Oregon). This is the Region that all later requests are sent to, unless you specify otherwise in an individual command." - from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html). Its not what the console shows. It can be whatever you want it to be.